# Symfony Doctrine: Remove ManyToMany association

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entites with many-to-many relationship: User and Tag.

```
class User{
   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="userList")
    */
    private $tagList;
}

class Tag{
   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="tagList")
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tags_users")
    */
    private $userList;
}
```

**Problem**

When I clear User's `tagList` I also want to remove user from removed tag's `userList`.

```
  $user->getTagList()->clear();
```

However in JoinTable `tags_users` I still can see tag-user association

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to make an owning and inverse side association, but only updating one side.

Check out the docs @ http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association

You should also call something like

```
$tag->removeUser($user);
```

You might add a function to your user entity to clear the tags

```
class User
{
    function clearTaglist()
    {
        foreach ($this->tagList as $tag) {
            $tag->removeUser($this);
        }

        $this->tagList->clear();
    }
}

class Tag {
    public function removeUser($user) 
    {
        $this->userList->removeElement($user);
    }
}
```

Cheers